# Interpreting a XDL Deadlock file

Tags: sql, ssms, azure-sql-database

I've generated the following XML + XDL: 
[image]

```
<deadlock>
  <victim-list>
    <victimProcess id="processc1eaf13468" />
  </victim-list>
  <process-list>
    <process id="processc1eaf13468" taskpriority="0" logused="892" waitresource="KEY: 11:72057594044547072 (c9fb1da9313f)" waittime="5244" ownerId="118489" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2017-06-27T15:17:20.250" XDES="0xc1e878c4c0" lockMode="S" schedulerid="1" kpid="144900" status="suspended" spid="119" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2017-06-27T15:20:22.437" lastbatchcompleted="2017-06-27T15:17:21.003" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.003" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="MIKBEN-W530" hostpid="30520" loginname="HuddleFm" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="118489" currentdb="11" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x05ff9bdd8b808318" queryplanhash="0x5cc8b281eb7808cd" line="1" stmtstart="256" stmtend="970" sqlhandle="0x020000005f1e5a01ca72346b429f4c909878692fbda9bbd20000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x0000000000000000" queryplanhash="0x0000000000000000" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
(@0 nvarchar(512),@1 int,@2 int,@3 bigint,@4 int,@5 int,@6 int,@7 datetime2(7),@8 int,@9 int,@10 bit,@11 bit,@12 nvarchar(max) )INSERT [dbo].[AppEvent]([MediaPath], [StorageProvider], [MediaType], [MediaSizeInBytes], [OldSessionState], [NewSessionState], [AppEventType], [EventDate], [DeviceSessionId], [TargetSessionId], [UserId], [ShouldBeDeleted], [HasBeenDeleted], [Payload], [LocalBrowserSessionGuid])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8, NULL, @9, @10, @11, NULL, @12)
SELECT [AppEventId]
FROM [dbo].[AppEvent]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT &gt; 0 AND [AppEventId] = scope_identity()   </inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="processc1e7c26ca8" taskpriority="0" logused="1064" waitresource="KEY: 11:72057594043170816 (40fd182c0dd9)" waittime="5396" ownerId="118496" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2017-06-27T15:17:20.890" XDES="0xc1e88b44c0" lockMode="S" schedulerid="1" kpid="194344" status="suspended" spid="123" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2017-06-27T15:20:22.283" lastbatchcompleted="2017-06-27T15:17:21.060" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.060" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="MIKBEN-W530" hostpid="30520" loginname="HuddleFm" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="118496" currentdb="11" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0xebf55cdceee65c9c" queryplanhash="0x5cc8b281eb7808cd" line="1" stmtstart="220" stmtend="936" sqlhandle="0x0200000066a736157a1b98ec891323511cd809b8ea3bf4a30000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x0000000000000000" queryplanhash="0x0000000000000000" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
(@0 int,@1 int,@2 bigint,@3 int,@4 int,@5 int,@6 datetime2(7),@7 int,@8 int,@9 bit,@10 bit,@11 nvarchar(max) )INSERT [dbo].[AppEvent]([MediaPath], [StorageProvider], [MediaType], [MediaSizeInBytes], [OldSessionState], [NewSessionState], [AppEventType], [EventDate], [DeviceSessionId], [TargetSessionId], [UserId], [ShouldBeDeleted], [HasBeenDeleted], [Payload], [LocalBrowserSessionGuid])
VALUES (NULL, @0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, NULL, @8, @9, @10, NULL, @11)
SELECT [AppEventId]
FROM [dbo].[AppEvent]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT &gt; 0 AND [AppEventId] = scope_identity()   </inputbuf>
    </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
    <keylock hobtid="72057594044547072" dbid="11" objectname="e6288089-3180-4261-aa4e-916673f3cd8a.dbo.DeviceSession" indexname="PK_dbo.DeviceSession" id="lockc1f1b6b300" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594044547072">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="processc1e7c26ca8" mode="X" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="processc1eaf13468" mode="S" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </keylock>
    <keylock hobtid="72057594043170816" dbid="11" objectname="e6288089-3180-4261-aa4e-916673f3cd8a.dbo.User" indexname="PK_dbo.User" id="lockc1f1b6c280" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594043170816">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="processc1eaf13468" mode="X" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="processc1e7c26ca8" mode="S" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </keylock>
  </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

I'm now trying to understand what's causing the deadlock; I've never interpreted this kind of log before.  I see that there is some contention between `User` and `DeviceSession` but I'm not sure where that's coming from.  How does one go about interpreting an XDL / Deadlock dump?

Comment: You'll probably be better asking this over at https://serverfault.com/ as it's not a programming question.  Good luck

Comment: Why server fault? Would be better at https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/858182/interpreting-a-deadlock-log-xdl-file | https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/177436/interpreting-xdl-deadlock-dumps-in-ssms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same INSERT statement is involved. You can make sure these inserts happen serially using sp_getapplock.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Alberto Morillo